# How to use a JMX RMI agent in a WebStart process?

Tags: java, jmx, jnlp, java-web-start

I am trying to implement a monitoring control based on an RMI connector for JMX, for an application launcher via WebStart.

The connectors work fine no matter how I start them when the application is started from the command-line or IDE. However, everything goes south when I try to inspect it when it's been launched by invoking the JNLP file with javaws.

I have tried several approaches:

- using the built-in JMX features, by specifying the following variables in JAVAWS_VM_ARGS (docs say it should work in 1.6, but people report it doesn't; they don't appear to be set at all in the resulting process, if I inspect it using the Attach API):

  ```
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=SOME_PORT_HERE
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  ```
- using the built-in JMX features, by specifying the following variables in the JNLP file (some say this shouldn't work, and indeed they don't seem to be set when I inspect with the Attach API; the JNLP is set with all-permissions as well):

  ```
  <property name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only" value="true" />
  <property name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.port" value="SOME_PORT_HERE" />
  <property name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate" value="false" />
  <property name="com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl" value="false" />
  ```
- using the built-in JMX features, by specifying the following variables using -J options to the calling `javaws` program (they don't appear to be set at all in the resulting process, if I inspect it using the Attach API):

  ```
  -J-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -J-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
  -J-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=SOME_PORT_HERE
  -J-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -J-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  ```
- using a custom JMXConnectorServer with the following code (connection is still refused as with the previous attempts, with "Connection Failed. Retry? The connection did not succeed."):

  ```
      try {
          final MBeanServer  mbs     = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
          final String       jmxPort = System.getProperty("jmx.port");

          if (jmxPort != null) {
              final int port = Integer.parseInt(jmxPort);

              System.out.println("settings JMX properties");
              System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");
              Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
              env.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false");
              env.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false");
              env.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only", "true");
              System.out.println("Creating Locate Registry");
              LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
              System.out.println("Creating JMX Service URL");
              JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:" + port + "/server");
              System.out.println("Creating new JMX Connector Server");
              JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);
              cs.start();
          }
      } catch (final RemoteException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (final IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```

I try to connect with JConsole (ultimately, this will be done from another program, but I try from JConsole to verify the JMX service is running correctly) with this JMXServiceURL:

```
    service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:SOME_PORT_HERE/jmxrmi
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this, either programmatically or how to get these properties passed to the WebStart-ed process?

Thanks in advance.

### Additional Notes

- this is for Java 1.6+ (not 1.5).
- these options **do** work when I invoke my program directly and pass them via the command-line.
- Some mentioned specifying the IP directly, using java.rmi.server.hostname=YOUR_IP. However, this doesn't seem require when the process is started normally, so I don't think it would be relevant to the WebStart scenario.
- I can use a connection with the Attach API to connect to a process by PID with JConsole or JVisualVM, but ultimately the product cannot rely on this, as it requires a JDK or to bundle the tools.jar, and I don't think there are open alternatives to this. If there is, that would actually be a lot easier so let me know if you know one.

---

**Update:**

Actually, when using my last example with an explicit `JMXConnectorServer`, I get an NPE at the launch-time of the WebStart process, with:

```
12:39:28,743 WARN  [App] [trce] java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jboss.security.jndi.LoginInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(LoginInitialContextFactory.java:81)
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:619)
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:412)
 // line invoking .start() on the JMXConnectorServer's instance
```

Comment: i know you don't want "did you try" comments, but for the last example, did you try using a url like: `"service:jmx:rmi://localhost:" + port + "/jndi/rmi://localhost:" + port + "/server"`.  also, i assume your webstart app is granted all permissions?

Comment: @jtahlborn: doesn't work either. And I have granted all-permissions in the JNLp, yes (see point 2).

Comment: i think the last solution could work, the problem seems to be that your configured default initial context is a jboss context.  you need to make the rmi stuff not using the jboss context.  possibly need to pass in an initial context factory of something like "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory", see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html

Comment: @jtahlborn: Yeah that looks like the issue indeed. Unfortunately I need this InitialContext to be set. BUT, that reminds me of a similar issue I encountered a while back (completely different and unrelated context) where I did manage to swap in place initial contexts. That could be something to try here. I'll see how it goes and get back if I get something of interest for this thread :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jtahlborn: that being said, I'm still clueless as to why it would work when invoked from the command-line but not via webstart. (both scenarios appear to be loading that the JNDI properties files setting this initial context).

Comment: @jtahlborn: Ok, I managed to get it working. Still puzzled as to why it differs between normal and webstarted executions, but I assume there's just something nasty going on and their setup must slightly differ somewhere (I hope, for my sanity). Good news is that indeed I could temporarily bypass/shortcut the initial ctxt to be looked up just for the duration of the JMX setup, and then everything's OK: can connect from JConsole or any client to the Ws-ed process. Sweet. Longish, but sweet nonetheless. Will post details of the solution later, but thanks a lot for the back-and-forth and the help!

Comment: nifty, i'm glad you got it working.  i'm sure others would appreciate the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with [jtahlborn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552759/jtahlborn) in the question's comment, we worked out that this was really specific to the application's setup.

There are some pitfalls to address to make JMX work for WebStart-ed applications, and there's also some implications to the use of multiple JNDI context factories.

In this particular case, the application had a `jndi.properties` read on startup and populating configuration settings, so a JBoss JNDI context factory was already even at the call point of the static block of the WebStart-ed application's entry-point / main-class.

As these JNDI properties were necessary for the rest of the program, the solution is simply to override these properties when creating the `JMXServerConnector` programmatically.

Here's an example:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static Properties   initProperties() {
        return (new Properties() {{
            // overrides for the JNDI factory
            // mostly changing the INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY from:
            //   "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory"
            // to:
            put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost/");

            // Required JMX properties and other things ...
            //  YMMV of course, these were for my current settings
            put("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");
            put("java.rmi.server.hostname", host); // host needs to be an IP
            put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false");
            put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false");
            put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only", "true");
            put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port", String.valueOf(port));
        }});
    }
```

and:

```
    // error handling left out for clarity
    private static void startJMXAgent() throws TheWorld {
        Registry           reg  = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        JMXConnectorServer cs   =
            JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(
                new JMXServiceURL(
                    "service:jmx:rmi://" + host + ":" + port + "/" +
                    "jndi/rmi://" + host + ":" + port + "/" +
                    servicename
                ),
                initProperties(),
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
            );
        cs.start();
    }
```

---

*Note:* I assume you could probably do it the other way around and override these properties on the command-line or in the JNLP file, and then reset them to whatever is needed for later contexts. However, this didn't fit the use case here so I didn't really look into it.

Answer (score 0):

try setting following argument from command line on windows

set JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9400 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

and then start the jnlp file from that same command prompt. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. However, re-read my question: this approach has been tried and is not be reliable in some circumstances. `using the built-in JMX features, by specifying the following variables in JAVAWS_VM_ARGS (docs say it should work in 1.6, but people report it doesn't; they don't appear to be set at all in the resulting process, if I inspect it using the Attach API): [...]`.

One of the issues is that in some environments the WS launcher will fork and these won't be passed to the forked child. You can try to specify a nofork option as well, but this depends on the system and WS may ignore it.